# Migration from JaxRS to Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to migrate from Jax RS to Spring Rest, I am not sure how to add base address of URL for Spring rest.

I tried adding `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, but did not help

```
<jaxrs:server address="/search-service">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        ...all service classes
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="wadlGenerator"/>
        <ref bean="cors-filter"/>
        <ref bean="soaJsonJaxbProvider"/>
        <ref bean="exceptionMapper"/>
        <ref bean="searchContextProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", produces=org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes=org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class SearchService {
@PostMapping
public ServiceResponse<searchDTO> search(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, ServiceRequest<searchDTO> request) {
....method
}
```

How to add Spring rest instead of jaxrs:server in beans.xml.

Comment: can you add your controller class? Typically you annotate that with the various base paths, http methods and so on in the controller and register the bean with the application context using annotations or beans.xml

Comment: @stringy05 - How do I add details to beans.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

For spring to discover the annotated class, you need to add the `annotation-driven` tag and also `component-scan`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans> <!-- add in all the namespace declarations you need-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourpackage" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

The alternative is to use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` when you load the spring context, which is a fully java / annotation configured setup instead of the XML config.

For the gory details, refer to the spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-metadata: